# B1/B2 Visa - Additional information requested

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I was denied a B visa yesterday. The visa officer said that I need to upload my CV to provide additional information. I am an Indian, currently a PhD student in Germany and want to travel to the US to visit my girlfriend. Any advice on how detailed/professional the CV should be? Since I work in a domain which uses liberal amounts of jargon, Is it ok to upload my academic CV or should I rewrite everything to make it understandable to lay-persons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't rewrite - you're following their instructions, and they didn't ask you to rewrite it 'simpler'.  And remember, everything is jargon to someone.  I'd recommend uploading as is - it's likely to look more at your work experience locations, I'd imagine, rather than your specific skill set, and if they're looking at skill set, they'll have advisors or specialists that can review that (like IT recuiters, for example, who specialise in knowing and understanding IT jargon (well, in theory)).

If they'd wanted a 'simpler' CV, they'd advise you to do so, as there are many people applying who wouldn't even have thought to do what you're suggesting.